# Markov Chains with multiple invariant distributions

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Is it possible for a Markov chain to have 2 or more invariant distributions? I'm trying to understand the Perron-Frobenius Theorem, and it seems like it's saying that an eigenvector of P is unique as long as its components are positive? Of course, there can be infinitely many of these distributions too, but I am concerned with the finite case. I would love some insight on why it is not possible to have multiple invariant distributions for Markov chains!

Comment: By "two" do you mean "exactly 2", or do you mean "more than 1"?

Comment: Thanks for the question kimchi. I mean any finite number larger than 1.

Comment: If your matrix is the identity matrix, then there will be an infinite number of invariant distributions...

Answer (score 1):

The set of stationary distributions is a convex set.  If it is not a singleton, it contains the line segment connecting any two distinct stationary distributions.  So its cardinality cannot be a finite number greater than 1.  Either it's unique or there are infinitely many of them.